# Find missing entries in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-4.0

I have a datatable used to bind a gridview; it contains a DateTime column denoting week start dates (11/28, 12/05, 12/12, 12/26 with 12/19 missing).

I want to modify the datatable to include the missing dates so when gridview is populated the missing dates would give users a visual indication that some entries are missing (i.e. data rows that only have WeekStartdate column).

I can use Linq to get the min and max dates in the datatable but was wondering if there is a more elequant way of adding the missing entries than looping through the datatable from min date to max date and check for missing dates. I would then need to create a data row containing only the date column and add it to datatable.

Comment: You may add to the DataTable a column including missing dates. After binding the GridView to the DataTable, set the Visible attribute of the DateTime column (or of the new Column) to false. Use the CellFormatting event to give in the still visible column a visual indication that will depend on the content of the 2 columns.

Comment: @Graffito thank for the response. I was hoping there would a nice Linq statement to do this. I ended up doing what I didn't want to do: loop through data table items and insert missing dates; then bind the gridview. I can use grid's OnRowDataBound do apply some CSS style to missing entry rows. I would still love to see a more elegant way of manipulating the data table, if there is one.